# Teamcity deploy command line

Tags: iis, cmd, teamcity, webdeploy

I've configured TeamCity for build and deploy IIS app.
Everything works fine. Here is my command line param:

> -verb:sync -source:package="webapi-%dep.xxx.build.counter%.zip"
>   -dest:contentpath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test2.com\bin",computerName="www",userName="uuu",password="ccc",includeAcls="False"
>   -AllowUntrusted -verbose

So, artifacts zip file should extract files to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test2.com\bin folder. In bin folder i have a lot of xml and config files (zip file dont include this files). In every deploy it delete bin folder and extract zip files.

How can I skip deleting? I just need publish with replace what i have in archive without deleting another files?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

add one more parameter:

```
-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
```

according to [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd568992(v=ws.10)):

In a **sync** operation, blocks deletions of files on the destination computer that do not exist on the source computer. This rule applies to the contentPath, dirPath, and filePath providers. This rule is disabled by default.